# Herança e manipulação de métodos de uma superclasse

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança

A herança é dita que uma subclasse herda todos os métodos de uma super classe. Mas ao fazer

```
class Soma{
    private double total;
    public void setSoma(double s1, double s2)
    {
        total = s1+s2;
    }
    public double getSoma()
    {
        return total;
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Calculos extends Soma{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double v1, v2;
        Scanner insere = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Digite o primeiro valor: ");
        v1 = insere.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Digite o segundo valor: ");
        v2 = insere.nextDouble();
        setSoma(v1, v2);
        System.out.printf("O resultado da soma é %.2f", getSoma());
    }
}
```

Dá erro pois a subclasse não consegue manipular os métodos da superclasse de forma direta. Então como seria?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Aquilo que julgo que você pretende, neste caso, não tem nada a haver com herança.

O que você quer é usar a classe *Soma*, para isso é necessário criar uma instância dela com o operador `new`, tal como você fez quando necessitou de utilizar a classe *Scanner*.

O código será assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double v1, v2;
    Scanner insere = new Scanner(System.in);
    Soma soma = new Soma();

    System.out.print("Digite o primeiro valor: ");
    v1 = insere.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Digite o segundo valor: ");
    v2 = insere.nextDouble();
    soma.setSoma(v1, v2);
    System.out.printf("O resultado da soma é %.2f", soma.getSoma());
}
```

Herança é outra coisa, ela é usada quando você quer estender(daí o Java utilizar o operador *extends*) as capacidades de uma classe, mantendo as da classe herdada.

Suponha que você quer uma classe que faça somas e subtrações. Como você já tem uma classe que faz somas cria uma nova que *extends* dela:

```
class Calculos extends Soma{

    private double total;
    public void setSubtracao(double s1, double s2)
    {
        total = s1-s2;
    }
    public double getSubtracao()
    {
        return total;
    }
}
```

Agora, a classe *Calculos*, tem acesso, não só aos métodos declarados nela, mas também aos da classe *Soma*:

```
Calculos calculos = new Calculos();

calculos.setSoma(10.5,15.5)
double soma = calculos.getSoma();

calculos.setSubtracao(20.5,10.5);
double subtracao = calculos.getSubtracao();
```

Answer (score 2):

Não se deve usar herança desta forma. Na verdade é herança é algo ruim e só deve ser usada em último caso, quando ela se prova mais benéfica que as dificuldades que sua implementação traz. Sempre é melhor usar composição.

Mas eu entendo que você está apenas tentando fazer um teste com herança.

Tem algumas formas de fazer isto mas você realmente não pode acessar métodos de instância no método estático diretamente. Só é possível fazer isto instanciando a própria classe. Aí você pode acessar qualquer membro através do objeto instanciado.

Também separei o instanciamento da execução. Assim fica mais organizado mesmo que isto não seja necessário para funcionar. Note que no método `executa()` eu pude chamar normalmente qualquer membro, mesmo os herdado porque este método é de instância e não estático. O ramaral deu um exemplo na resposta dele sem precisar criar um método extra mas usa a mesma solução de instanciar a classe para acessar os membros.

Assim funciona:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculos extends Soma {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculos calculo = new Calculos();
        calculo.executa();
    }
    public void executa() {
        double v1, v2;
        Scanner insere = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Digite o primeiro valor: ");
        v1 = insere.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Digite o segundo valor: ");
        v2 = insere.nextDouble();
        setSoma(v1, v2);
        System.out.printf("O resultado da soma eh %.2f", getSoma());
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/PdRqIj). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/CompositonInsteadInheritance). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/CompositonInsteadInheritance.java).